# XAMPP Server Crashes after Move to New Mac

Tags: macos, xampp

I moved my application to my new Mac Mini using Migration Assistant. When I tried to start the XAMPP server, it crashes saying launch path not accessible. I've set the permission to allow everyone to read or write it, but it still doesn't work. Am I missing a permission somewhere? Here's the first part of the dump:

```
Process:         XAMPP Control [3203]
```

Path:            /Applications/XAMPP/XAMPP Control.app/Contents/MacOS/XAMPP Control
Identifier:      org.apachefriends.XAMPP_Control
Version:         1.7.3-beta1 (B8B.1)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [178]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-01-15 11:29:17.183 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C3103)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          414553 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           1076645
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  3055 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   8
Anonymous UUID:                      E9F33D4F-5808-AB42-1B4B-32662668A5AF

Crashed Thread:  13

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x92f5412b **raiseError + 219
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x9924e52e objc_exception_throw + 230
2   CoreFoundation                      0x92eb3bbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
3   Foundation                          0x9708ddc5 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:] + 521
4   Foundation                          0x97100447 -[NSConcreteTask launch] + 40
5   Apache                              0x03f7f508 -[ApacheModule(PRIVAT) syntaxCheck] + 252
6   Apache                              0x03f7ebb0 -[ApacheModule runStartTests] + 120
7   XAMPP Control                       0x0000727f -[XPModule start] + 143
8   XAMPP Control                       0x00008343 -[XPModuleViewController doStart] + 73
9   Foundation                          0x970c11d8 -[NSThread main] + 45
10  Foundation                          0x970c115b _*NSThread*_main** + 1396
11  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9821c557 _pthread_start + 344
12  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x98206cee thread_start + 34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Migration Assistant didn't copy over all the XAMPP files. The xamppfiles directory was empty. Now to get MySQL to run.